# How to use the same certs when moving server

Tags: iis, ssl-certificate, windows-server-2016

On my old server, I kept all the cert requests and cert responses. I've now had to move server and I can't find out how to re-use the certs.

In IIS I click on Complete Certificate Request and choose the `.crt` file and name it a friendly name. I click OK and I can see it in server certs as an entry. But it doesn't reamin! I then leave this window and return to it and the cert is no longer there.

Why can't I use the existing response file?

Comment: I think that is an answer then @jscott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neither the certificate request file, nor the CA provided certificate (as you call it 'response') contain the private key. You need to export the private key from the old server or, if the old certificate is not marked 'exportable', re-key the certificate with the CA.

Comment: Is the re-key the same as a re-issue (when I click on re-issue I still have to enter my cert request). Because Komodo have provided the new cert but the same issue persists :( The issue I have is, the old server is no more

Comment: You will need to generate a new CSR on the new server. Provide the same info as in the original CSR. Generating the CSR creates a new private key stored on the new server. Submit the new CSR to Comodo as a [re-issue request](https://comodosslstore.com/blog/procedure-for-a-free-re-issuing-of-a-comodo-ssl-certificate.html). Once you complete the import of the newly issued cert, you may want to [export a PFX containing the private key](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754329(v=ws.11).aspx) and keep it somewhere safe.